# Python3 different behaviour between latin-1 and cp1252 when decoding unmapped characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, cp1252

I'm trying to read in Python3 a text file specifying encoding **cp1252** which has unmapped characters (for instance byte **0x8d**).

```
with open(inputfilename, mode='r', encoding='cp1252') as inputfile:
    print(inputfile.readlines())
```

I obviously get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(inputfile.readlines())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 14: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'd like to understand why, when reading the same file with encoding **latin-1**, I don't get the same exception and the byte **0x8d** is represented as hex string:

```
$ python3 test.py
['This is a test\x8d file\n']
```

As far as i know byte **0x8d** does not have a match on both encodings (**latin-1** and **cp1252**). What am I missing? Why Python3 behaviour is different?

Comment: latin-1 is special in that it will decode any bytestring, returning the original byte if it has no latin-1 equivalent.  Other encodings (like cp1252) will raise UnicodeDecodeError is the byte cannot be mapped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Why Python developers chose to handle latin-1 this way?
Is there any official reference about this behaviour?
Are there other "special" encodings?

Comment: I _believe_ that this is a universal property of latin-1, rather than a Python-specific behaviour, but I can't find any authoritative confirmation of this, which is why I'm commenting instead of answering.  AFAIK no other text-encoding defines this behaviour.

Comment: Latin-1 reserved 8x and 9x, and such values were used for C1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes), as you note, it is not a random reason. Because Latin1 should not use them, and if someone use it in Latin1, there should be C1, there is not much ambiguity (but against the Python mantra: "better explicit then implicit")

Answer (score 0):

from the docs: The simplest text encoding (called 'latin-1' or 'iso-8859-1') maps the code points 0–255 to the bytes 0x0–0xff

https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html